# SQL Server import from flat file match columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a flat flat that has 12 columns. The table has more than 30 columns.
Through SQL Server 2008, how do I go about importing the data and then matching the fields from the flat file to actual fields in the table? I know there is a wizard to do this but I could not see how to actually match the fields up.

```
   SQL Server 2008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the database, tasks -> import data -> source choose your flat file -> target choose you database -> next wizard page choose your table as the target from the flat file (instead of default new table) -> edit advanced properties and choose the target columns for your flat file columns.

Then you start and/or save the SSIS package. If your data needs to convert in any way then you create a visual studio business intelligence - integration project -> and then add your ssis.dtsx package to the project to modify the columns conversions, error handlings, etc.
Bit in fact you can try start the ssis package from the wizard first.