# How can I insert text file content from fingerprint into SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am a beginner in asp.net and I have a .txt file that export from fingerprint. I wonder if I can import content of the file into SQL Server 2008 with the same column?

Here is the content of the file:

```
No      Mchn    EnNo        Name        Mode    IOMd    DateTime
00001   1       00000003                33      0       2012/01/05  10:48:36
00002   1       00000014                33      0       2012/01/07  11:43:02
00003   1       00000014                33      0       2012/01/07  11:43:02
00004   1       00000022                33      0       2012/01/07  11:47:33
00005   1       00000020                33      0       2012/01/07  11:52:40
00006   1       00000023                33      0       2012/01/07  11:56:48
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to get the data into SQL server will be using the Import/Export wizard.  Try the following steps.

- In SQL Server Management Studio access the import export wizard by right clicking on the database name and choosing Tasks > Import Data.

  Then select the [datasource as flat file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187017(v=sql.100).aspx)

  Choose your file and make the appropriate selections for delimiters and end of line markers.

  The wizard will then give you the option to create a new table or [import into an existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641588/sql-server-import-from-flat-file-match-columns).

This should allow you to get the data into the database.  If you want the wizard can save the configuration as an SSIS package so you can use it on more than one file.